# Unable to use CA2CT and CW2T in Visual Studio 2022 when C++20 is specified

Tags: c++, mfc, c++20, atl, visual-studio-2022

I am having a problem trying to use C++20 with Visual Studio 2022:

For example:

- `CA2CT`
- `CW2T`
- `CA2W`

> error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from `ATL::CA2W` to `ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>>`

If I revert to C++17 it is fine.

Why is this?

---

Here is an example:

```
CLSID AppCLSID ; 
if (SUCCEEDED(::CLSIDFromProgID(CT2W(rstrProgID), &AppCLSID) ) ) 
{
    LPOLESTR pszName = NULL ; 
    if (SUCCEEDED(::ProgIDFromCLSID(AppCLSID, &pszName) ) ) 
    {
        CString strAppID = CW2T(pszName); 
    }
}
```

Note that `rStrProgId` could be values like `_T("Word.Application")`.

The above scpecific case the error is:

> error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from `ATL::CW2W` to `ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>>`

---

Other code snippets as examples:

#### Example 2

`CString strCalendarName = CA2CT(pName->GetText(), CP_UTF8);`

(the value of `pName->GetText()` is `const char *)`.

---

#### Update

Doing what @Inspectable says resolves the one issue.

The others (examples) that won't compile are:

```
std::string s1 = CT2A(strNameText);
CString strStudent1 = CA2CT(pElement1->GetText(), CP_UTF8);
```

There are other compiling issues but I feel they are outside the scope of this question.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani This is annoying as it affects so much code! I have updated the question with a specific example that relates to teh warning in question.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani In my various situations I need to cater for buiulding 32 bit and 64 bit too.

Comment: I am not quite sure what is going on, let's see if it gets reopened. By the way, I meant `(const char*)`, I think it's needed for CStringA copy constructor.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani It got reopened. :) Let me know if there is anything you would like me to add to the question.

Comment: `CString strAppID = CW2T(pszName);` doesn't compile for me on C++14, C++17, or C++20. Though, why aren't you using `CString strAppID{ pszName };` instead? This will call either of the conversion constructors, and fail to compile when `_CSTRING_DISABLE_NARROW_WIDE_CONVERSION` is defined and `CString` expands to `CStringA`. Combining both is the safe way forward (unless you're still maintaining compatibility with Windows 95).

Comment: @IInspectable Win 7 SP1 is the min app for support. The above compiles for me on c++17. I’ll try your suggestion in that one instance.

Comment: @IInspectable It worked, thanks. But i have not added that `_CSTRING_DISABLE_NARROW_WIDE_CONVERSION` flag or anything to the project. I updated the question.

Comment: @IInspectable It will not compile with that flag set (for either c++ versions). Subject for other discussion.

Comment: `std::string s1{ CT2A(strNameText) };` fixes one of them.

Comment: Using braces appears to fix the others too `CString strName{ CA2CT(pTeachingItemName->GetText(), CP_UTF8) };`.

Comment: But why they work with braces and not the the other way - a mystery to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue evidently relates to `/permissive-` compiler option. If c++20 is selected, the compiler forces `/permissive-` option.

> [`/permissive-` (Standards conformance)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-170)
>
> The `/permissive-` option is implicitly set by the /std:c++latest option
> starting in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8, and in version 16.11 by
> the /std:c++20 option. `/permissive-` is required for `C++20` Modules
> support.

With `/permissive-` or `/std:c++20` enabled, the compiler will not allow `CStringA a = CW2A(L"123");` (I think because `CW2A/CA2W` use a conversion operator to return `TCHAR*` buffer to `CString`), so it needs `{}` initialization

```
CStringA a { CW2A(L"123") };
```

---

In this case it makes no difference with or without conformance, as far as I understand. But `{}` is preferred for initialization since c++11. For example it can check for narrowing conversion, and it's more consistent with other initialization forms:

```
char c = 256;//compiles with warning, narrowing conversion
char c {256};//won't compile
char c[] = { 1,2 };//ok
auto c {256};//compiles, auto -> int c
auto c = {256};//std::initializer_list, cout << *c.begin();
foo::foo(int i) : m_int{ i } {};//member initialization list
RECT rc{};//set all members to zero
```

Comment: Alright, but, why does "list initialization" work?

Comment: FYI. I now have the software compiling in C++20 mode. Not bad for an 18 year old application ... :)

Comment: @AndrewTruckle, updated the answer. Honestly I don't understand what was wrong `=` initialization and why they had to change it to this curly bracket thing. They might change it next year to `[<>]` initialization and they explain why `{}` is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat more historic[ally known] issue methinks.
AFAIK this relates to
implicit handling of `CString` classes (implicit operators: `operator LPCTSTR()` etc. - e.g. as opposed to `std::string`'s likely intentionally explicit `.c_str()` etc.).

[
Likely related topic:
https://aras-p.info/blog/2008/10/09/implicit-to-pointer-operators-must-die/
]

Which results in a required "double conversion" / "double transition" (sorry for inexact terms :( ) from RHS to LHS (`CString`), which was sloppily accepted by MSVC all the time (like so much other annoying sloppy MSVC handling), yet which e.g. gcc for a long time (forever?) has been disallowing (likely due to language spec requirements), resulting in fail when trying to do certain transitions to `CString` with gcc (better do NOT ask me how I know this  ).
The issue here should be resolvable by doing

```
CString strAppID = static_cast<LPCTSTR>(CW2T(pszName));
```

or

```
CString strAppID = CW2T(pszName).m_psz;
```

(BTW which one is better?

- `.m_psz` is implementation details (specific member) but interestingly T-agnostic
- `static_cast<LPCTSTR>` is non-implementation-specific but T-specific

)

Though, as commented elsewhere, these are source changes (potentially many) required for this C++ spec change switch. Though this is the quite usual business of making existing [imperfectly precise] code fit for other (usually more strict/precise) specs/environments.